# Why did the Endurance mission need to be manned at all?

Tags: interstellar

Given the implications of time dilation on the crew of the *Endurance* mission, why send people at all? TARS and CASE seem more than capable of operating the ships themselves and wouldn't care about how much time was passing for each other or back on Earth. Whoever they chose to rescue could have started Plan B without risking any more crew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the original script, the problem is that robots simply aren't reliable. Placing the survival of the entire human race into their hands is both unnecessarily *risky* (in the sense that they could malfunction) and unnecessarily *risk-averse* when they're already willing to treat their finest minds as expendable units:

> **COOPER:** *You’re taking a risk using ex-military for security. **They’re old, their control units are unpredictable ...***
>
> **WOMAN:** *Well, that’s what the government could spare.*

It should be noted that TARS and CASE apparently performed well above expectation.

Comment: Yes, and given that the survival of the whole human race is at stake, it makes sense to be willing to sacrifice the lives of explorers if it leads to even a slight increase in the chances the mission will be successful.

Comment: *"..the problem is that robots simply aren't reliable"*  Yes, Mann was a complete..  Oh sorry, you were talking about the **hardware.**  ;)